# How to change default mountpoint of external drives /media to any other location in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: automount, udev

I tried all the ways of udev rules and scripts but it only mounts VFAT format. If I attach an NTFS type pd all hd it shows "end point not connected".

Here is the script I used:

```udev
KERNEL!="sd[a-z][0-9]", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
# Import FS infos
IMPORT{program}="/sbin/blkid -o udev -p %N"
# Get a label if present, otherwise specify one
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}!="", ENV{dir_name}="%E{ID_FS_LABEL}"
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="", ENV{dir_name}="usbhd-%k"
# Global mount options
ACTION=="add", ENV{mount_options}="relatime"
# Filesystem-specific mount options
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="vfat|ntfs", ENV{mount_options}="$env{mount_options},utf8,gid=1 00,umask=002"
# Mount the device
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/mount -o $env{mount_options} /dev/%k /media/%E{dir_name}"
# Clean up after removal
ACTION=="remove", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/umount -l /media/%E{dir_name}", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /media/%E{dir_name}"
# Exit
LABEL="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
```

But it only mounts VFAT filesystems. I also tried using a GitHub script but it's not working, same result as the script above.

I just want to change the default mountpoint of usb and external hdd for all formats with full permission just like the `/media` mountpoint.

Comment: plz help me out of this... anyone

Comment: 1st question: do you have the ntfs tools installed so you have a driver that can mount ntfs?

Comment: no, i dont have that tool but ntfs filesysytem mounted in default path

Comment: @Rinzwind - is there any other way like edit the file where /media is set to automount for external usb's.... if u know a path of that file..... plz share me...

Comment: @RahulBarde Could you add to the question which Ubuntu release you are using?